# Cannot access remote path using host alias from etc\hosts

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials

on windows server 2016 I have entry in `etc\hosts` file like so:

`txe-build-svr 10.10.10.10`

when I try to access share on that host i do
`get-childitem -path \\10.10.10.10\c$`
 it works

when I do
`get-childitem -path \\txe-build-svr\c$`
I get an error

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\txe-build-svr\c$' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path \\txe-build-svr\c$
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\txe-build-svr\c$:String) [Get-ChildItem], 
ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

`etc\hosts` entry does work, and alias is being resolved to correct IP address.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem

Comment: so... the entry is in etc\hosts file. 
From what I know about computers - windows trying to resolve name to IP - first goes to etc\hosts, if not defined there  - goes to dns cache - if not available there - only then proceeds with DNS resolution

Comment: Is this in a (Windows) domain environment? If so, have you tried using the fully qualified host name, e.g. `\\txe-build-svr.domain.tld\c$`

Comment: @HelO'Ween no luck here.  txe-build-svr is an alias written to etc\hosts file so it does not have FQDN

Comment: I just realized that you have mixed up the order in your host file. It should read   `IP address   hostname`, not `hostname   IP address` like in your question: `txe-build-svr 10.10.10.10`.

Comment: @Hel O'Ween keen observation, but I have done this only in this question. I can ping txe-build-SVR no problem and it does resolve to correct ip